# How to insert custom template/block where I want?

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, template

Trying to insert custom template/block into specific place in => product.info.addto

for some reason my block appears either before or after and I can't manage to insert it anywhere else.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
<catalog_product_view>

    <reference name="content">

        <block type="amber_custom/catalog_product_custom" name="linked.product" template="amber/catalog/product/custom.phtml" after="product.reviews"/> <!-- trying inset it after this block but no luck -->

    </reference>

</catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

What is the problem, why it won't go there ?

To find out all the block names i'm using "ath" - advanced theme hint , it shows all the names correctly.

Comment: add alias in before or after. Find alias from your catalog.xml and local.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Changes

1. Copy `catalog/product/view.phtml` into to your theme if it isn't already (never directly edit core files or you could lose your changes)
2. Inside this template add `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('linked.product') ?>` to where you want it to render
3. In your layout XML change `<reference name="content">` to `<reference name="product.info">`

### Explanation

The problem arises because you're using `<reference name="content">` - `content` is a structural block and structural blocks will automatically render child blocks and this is your problem as it can be difficult to position blocks this way.

#### Why before/after isn't working for you

`after` isn't working for you because your block is using the reference `content` whilst `product.reviews` inside the reference of `product.info`.

You're best bet is to use `<reference name="product.info">` rather than `content` and then copy over `catalog/product/view.phtml` into your theme if it isn't already (**never edit the core or Ben Marks will hunt you down**).

Now inside this template add the following:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('linked.product') ?>
```

This will render your block where ever you add that line of code.

At first the above seems a bit strange and not so straight forward, but after you've done it a few times it becomes second nature and actually makes sense.

Comment: Thank you Ben, it really works ;) It seems to be a really good method, I did exactly what you suggested and surprisingly the effect was positive. However, this is a pretty good trick, unfortunately if I would like to create a module fully transferable it will not work. How can I do it or what I suppose to change to make it work ? I'm a quiet new in Magento and many things is a complete mystery for me :)